# Semantically correct XHTML markup

Tags: html, css, xhtml, semantic-markup

Just trying to get the hang of using the semantically correct XHTML markup.

Just writing the code for a small navigation item. Where each button has effectivly a title and a descrption. I thought a definition list would therefore be great so i wrote the following

```
<dl>
    <dt>Import images</dt>
    <dd>Read in new image names to database</dd>

    <dt>Exhibition Management</dt>
    <dd>Create / Delete an exhibition </dd>

    <dt>Image Management</dt>
    <dd>Edit name, medium and exhibition data  </dd>
</dl>
```

But...I want the above to be 3 buttons, each button containing the dt and dd text. How can i do this with the correct code? Normally  i would make each button a div and use that for the visual button behaviour (onHover and current page selection stuff).

Any advice please

Thanks

Comment: Button like `<input type="button" />` or `<button>` or a hyperlink `<a>` (which some people erroneously refer to as a button)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Read in new image names to database">Import images</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Create / Delete an exhibition">Exhibition Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Edit name, medium and exhibition data">Image Management</a></li>
</ul>
```

thats good enough.
using `<dl>` for navigation is not very clever. or use a `<span>` inside the `<li>` with the description. `<dd>` will give you much headache since they aren't inside the `<dt>` and don't care about its position and styling

Comment: great, thanks for the advice. Just the same adding an ul to the links is good enough then? Good to know.

Comment: Whereas -and this is for information only, I personally agree with you on the use of `ul`/`ol` for navigation- Stu Nicholls, of cssplay.co.uk advocates using `<dl>` for navigation menus: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/definition.html

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly confused by the use of your term "button". If you mean a link, then you could do:

```
<a href="dest.html" title="Read in new image names to database">Import images</a>
```

If, however, you mean the input tag, then one way to do this would be to use input type=image and then provide an alt description.

For instance:

```
<input type="image" src="image.jpg" value="Import images" alt="Read in new image names to database"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<label>` elements instead of `<dt>` elements:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <label for="import-images">Import images</label>
            <span id="import-images">Read in new image names to database</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <label for="exhibition-management">Exhibition Management</label>
            <span id="exhibition-management">Create / Delete an exhibition</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <label for="image-management">Image Management</label>
            <span id="image-management">Edit name, medium and exhibition data</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

... the `for` attribute of the `<label>` element need only match the `id` of another element in the document to be valid.

Comment: Thanks! If you really need to have the little blurbs like "Read in new image names to database" appear as tooltips (like they do with the `title` attribute) you could use something like the jQuery tooltip plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip and then you'd be able to include markup in them.